# Flexible PowerShell function for processing text content

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I am trying to write a PowerShell function that is very flexible in processing text content. The idea is to be able to pass a string from the pipeline, and my function will split it at "\r?\n" to get an array of strings, and then process it. I also want to be able to pass an array of objects and have my function convert each element to a string using Out-String, and then process it. Additionally, I want to be able to pass an array of FileInfo objects and have my function read all file contents for me. However, I am struggling to make it work. It seems that PowerShell requires me to use type or name to get pipeline objects. Is there a way to force it to pass pipeline objects to one of my parameters?

### Update

This is what I have right now. Apparently it doesn't work. The `$content` parameter simply can't get piped object. For example, `dir | Test` doesn't work.

```
Function Test {
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)] [Object] $content
    )

    Begin {
        if ($content -is [String]) {
            $content = [regex]::Split($content, "\r?\n")
        }
        if ($content -is [System.IO.FileInfo[]]) {
            $content = $content | ForEach-Object { $_.readalltext() }
        }

        if ($content -is [Array] -and $content -isnot [String[]]) {
            $content = $content | ForEach-Object { $_ | Out-String }
        }

    }
    Process {

        Write-Host $content.GetType()
        $content | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host $_
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Regex in the case is silly when you can use string split which is more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to determine what `$content` is when coming from the pipeline and your code seems overall good, but you're doing so in the [`begin` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#begin) of your function when you should do it in the [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process). `$content` doesn't yet exist in the `begin` block when bound from pipeline.

As aside, you will have to redefine your last condition:

```
$content -is [Array] -and $content -isnot [String[]]
```

Elements of an array are passed one by one thru the pipeline, it would be a very rare case where you pass in the whole array from pipeline by forcing it. This last condition as is, is likely to never be met.

Here is how you could start approaching the logic, see inline comments for details.

```
Function Test {
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Object] $Content
    )

    Begin {
        # this list is used on the last condition
        $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    }
    Process {
        # if content has new line characters
        # then we're dealing with a multi-line string
        if ($Content -match '\r?\n') {
            # split it and output it
            $Content -split '\r?\n'
        }
        # else if content is a FileInfo instance
        elseif ($Content -is [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
            # read it and output its content as a multi-line string
            $Content | Get-Content -Raw
        }
        # else, none of the above was met
        # you need to determine what you want to do here
        else {
            # we can capture each element from the pipeline
            # and then output it in the `end` block
            $list.Add($Content)
        }
    }
    end {
        # no more objects coming from pipeline
        # check if the list was populated
        if($list.Count) {
            # if it was, output the captured objects
            # as a string
            $list.ToArray() | Out-String
        }
    }
}
```